# WSO2 api manager and SSO

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-api-manager

I'm using wso2am 2.0.0 and trying to configure SSO for access to the store and publisher application.
I'm not using wso2 IS but just configured the api manager directly to my IdP server(I have edited the site.json file to with my IdP setting)

I'm getting this exception after being authenticated to my IdP:
 **SAML Response contains invalid number of assertions. {org.wso2.carbon.hostobjects.sso.SAMLSSORelyingPartyObject}**

It look like my SAML response isn't correct but i'm unable to find why?

Answer (score 2):

There was no problem with my SAML response .
The problem was caused by a difference between my IdP server and the api manager timezone (they are deployed in two different environment), so the exception is thrown when comparing the current time in the gateway with the **NotBefore/NotOnOrAfter**

So may be a more significant error message could help

Comment: You can create a JIRA for the improvement here at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY

Answer (score 1):

You can use an online SAML Response decoders like [this](https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/toolbox/samlDecode.jsp) and see what's wrong with you SAML response.

Another option is to use [SAML Tracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/) in firefox.

Comment: I second that SAML Tracer for Firefox is  a great tool to inspect SAML response.